# JavaScript it's not running in page from a .js file

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a problem with some scripts of JavaScript. I render on my page some charts from Charts.js, the values for the charts are sent from the backend with some view functions from Django, these function return a JsonResponse, on the urls which are connected with these functions are sending some array which contains a hash-map aka json file that contains the values for the charts fields. With Ajax I take those values from the urls and inject them in JavaScript code that handles the charts rendering. If I put the JavaScript code in a .js file and call the file in HTML it doesn't work, if I put the JS code in a `<script>` tag it works. How can I put the code into a file?

The JS code:

```
// Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

        function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
            // *     example: number_format(1234.56, 2, ',', ' ');
            // *     return: '1 234,56'
            number = (number + '').replace(',', '').replace(' ', '');
            var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
                prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
                sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
                dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
                s = '',
                toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
                    var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
                    return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
                };
            // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
            s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
            if (s[0].length > 3) {
                s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
            }
            if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
                s[1] = s[1] || '';
                s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
            }
            return s.join(dec);
        }

        // Area Chart Example
        var incomes_state = {
            'months': [],
            'values': [],
        }
        var incomesChartAreaURL = '/users/dashboard/incomes-chart-area/'

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: incomesChartAreaURL,
            success: function (response) {
                for (var i in response) {
                    var key = Object.keys(response[i])[0]
                    var value = Object.values(response[i])[0]
                    incomes_state.months.push(key)
                    incomes_state.values.push(value)
                }
                buildIncomesChartArea()
            }
        })

        function buildIncomesChartArea() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("incomesAreaChart");
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: incomes_state.months,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Incomes",
                        lineTension: 0.3,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                        pointRadius: 3,
                        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                        pointHoverRadius: 3,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        pointBorderWidth: 2,
                        data: incomes_state.values,
                    }],
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 10,
                            right: 25,
                            top: 25,
                            bottom: 0
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            time: {
                                unit: 'date'
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                drawBorder: false
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                maxTicksLimit: 7
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                                padding: 10,
                                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                    return '$' + number_format(value);
                                }
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                                zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                                drawBorder: false,
                                borderDash: [2],
                                zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
                            }
                        }],
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                        bodyFontColor: "#858796",
                        titleMarginBottom: 10,
                        titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
                        titleFontSize: 14,
                        borderColor: '#dddfeb',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        xPadding: 15,
                        yPadding: 15,
                        displayColors: false,
                        intersect: false,
                        mode: 'index',
                        caretPadding: 10,
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function (tooltipItem, chart) {
                                var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                                return datasetLabel + ': $' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

        function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
            // *     example: number_format(1234.56, 2, ',', ' ');
            // *     return: '1 234,56'
            number = (number + '').replace(',', '').replace(' ', '');
            var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
                prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
                sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
                dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
                s = '',
                toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
                    var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
                    return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
                };
            // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
            s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
            if (s[0].length > 3) {
                s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
            }
            if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
                s[1] = s[1] || '';
                s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
            }
            return s.join(dec);
        }

        // Area Chart Example
        var spendings_state = {
            'months': [],
            'values': [],
        }
        var spendingsChartAreaURL = '/users/dashboard/spendings-chart-area/'

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: spendingsChartAreaURL,
            success: function (response) {
                for (var i in response) {
                    var key = Object.keys(response[i])[0]
                    var value = Object.values(response[i])[0]
                    spendings_state.months.push(key)
                    spendings_state.values.push(value)
                }
                buildSpendingsChartArea()
            }
        })

        function buildSpendingsChartArea() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("spendingsAreaChart");
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: spendings_state.months,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Spendings",
                        lineTension: 0.3,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(216, 0, 0, 0.05)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(216, 0, 0, 1)",
                        pointRadius: 3,
                        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(216, 0, 0, 1)",
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(216, 0, 0, 1)",
                        pointHoverRadius: 3,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(216, 0, 0, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(216, 0, 0, 1)",
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        pointBorderWidth: 2,
                        data: spendings_state.values,
                    }],
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 10,
                            right: 25,
                            top: 25,
                            bottom: 0
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            time: {
                                unit: 'date'
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                drawBorder: false
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                maxTicksLimit: 7
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                                padding: 10,
                                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                    return '$' + number_format(value);
                                }
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                                zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                                drawBorder: false,
                                borderDash: [2],
                                zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
                            }
                        }],
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                        bodyFontColor: "#858796",
                        titleMarginBottom: 10,
                        titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
                        titleFontSize: 14,
                        borderColor: '#dddfeb',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        xPadding: 15,
                        yPadding: 15,
                        displayColors: false,
                        intersect: false,
                        mode: 'index',
                        caretPadding: 10,
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function (tooltipItem, chart) {
                                var datasetLabel = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                                return datasetLabel + ': $' + number_format(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

        // Pie Chart Example
        var incomes_pie = {
            'names': [],
            'values': [],
        }
        var incomesChartPieURL = '/users/dashboard/incomes-chart-pie/'

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: incomesChartPieURL,
            success: function (response) {
                for (var i in response) {
                    var key = Object.keys(response[i])[0]
                    var value = Object.values(response[i])[0]
                    incomes_pie.names.push(key)
                    incomes_pie.values.push(value)
                }
                buildIncomesChartPie()
            }
        })
        function buildIncomesChartPie() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("incomesPieChart");
            var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: incomes_pie.names,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: incomes_pie.values,
                        backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc', '#e63900', '#7e98e7',
                        '#4de6ad', '#85d4e0', '#ff6633', '#a9baef', '#a6f2d6', '#ade2eb', '#ffb399'],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf', '#b32d00', '#5376df',
                        '#20df99', '#47bfd1', '#ff4000', '#7e98e7', '#79ecc2', '#85d4e0', '#ff8c66'],
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
                    }],
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    tooltips: {
                        backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                        bodyFontColor: "#858796",
                        borderColor: '#dddfeb',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        xPadding: 15,
                        yPadding: 15,
                        displayColors: false,
                        caretPadding: 10,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    cutoutPercentage: 80,
                },
            });
        }


        // Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

        // Pie Chart Example
        var spendings_pie = {
            'names': [],
            'values': [],
        }
        var spendingsChartPieURL = '/users/dashboard/spendings-chart-pie/'

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: spendingsChartPieURL,
            success: function (response) {
                for (var i in response) {
                    var key = Object.keys(response[i])[0]
                    var value = Object.values(response[i])[0]
                    spendings_pie.names.push(key)
                    spendings_pie.values.push(value)
                }
                buildSpendingsChartPie()
            }
        })
        function buildSpendingsChartPie() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("spendingsPieChart");
            var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: spendings_pie.names,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: spendings_pie.values,
                        backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc', '#e63900', '#7e98e7',
                        '#4de6ad', '#85d4e0', '#ff6633', '#a9baef'],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf', '#b32d00', '#5376df',
                        '#20df99', '#47bfd1', '#ff4000', '#7e98e7'],
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
                    }],
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    tooltips: {
                        backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                        bodyFontColor: "#858796",
                        borderColor: '#dddfeb',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        xPadding: 15,
                        yPadding: 15,
                        displayColors: false,
                        caretPadding: 10,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    cutoutPercentage: 80,
                },
            });
        }
```

the view function from the backend

```
def incomes_chart_area(request):
    incomes_data, date_distance, checks = [], -1, 12
    first_income = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    last_income = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    if first_income and last_income:
        date_distance = (last_income.created_date - first_income.created_date).days
    if  1 <= date_distance <= 365:
        year, month = first_income.created_date.year, first_income.created_date.month
        while checks:
            date = datetime(year, month, 1)
            if month == 12:
                incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=year, created_date__month=month)
                incomes_data.append({date.strftime('%b'): assembly(incomes)})
                month = 1
                year += 1
            else:
                incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=year, created_date__month=month)
                incomes_data.append({date.strftime('%b'): assembly(incomes)})
                month += 1
            checks -= 1
    elif date_distance > 0:
        year, month = last_income.created_date.year - 1, last_income.created_date.month + 1
        while checks:
            date = datetime(year, month, 1)
            if month == 12:
                incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=year, created_date__month=month)
                incomes_data.append({date.strftime('%b'): assembly(incomes)})
                month = 1
                year += 1
            else:
                incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=year, created_date__month=month)
                incomes_data.append({date.strftime('%b'): assembly(incomes)})
                month += 1
            checks -= 1
    elif date_distance == 0:
        year, month = first_income.created_date.year, first_income.created_date.month
        while checks:
            date = datetime(year, month, 1)
            if month == 12:
                incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=year, created_date__month=month)
                incomes_data.append({date.strftime('%b'): assembly(incomes)})
                month = 1
                year += 1
            else:
                incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=year, created_date__month=month)
                incomes_data.append({date.strftime('%b'): assembly(incomes)})
                month += 1
            checks -= 1
    return JsonResponse(incomes_data, safe=False)

def incomes_chart_pie(request):
    incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=datetime.now().year, created_date__month=datetime.now().month)
    total_incomes = assembly(incomes)
    incomes_data, categories = [], ['Salary', 'Awards', 'Grants', 'Sale', 'Dividents', 'Rental', 'Refunds', 'Coupons', 'Lottery', 'Capital', 'Investments', 'Gift', 'Others']
    for category in categories:
        category_incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__year=datetime.now().year, created_date__month=datetime.now().month, category=category)
        total_category_incomes = assembly(category_incomes)
        if total_incomes and total_category_incomes:
            incomes_data.append({category: round((total_category_incomes / total_incomes) * 100, 2)})
    return JsonResponse(incomes_data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in the file in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` (if you're able to use jQuery) or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});` elsewise?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the last part with hte document.addEventListener, why I need to add an eventListener?

Comment: You fill HTML elements with data you've asynchronously loaded so you'll first need to wait for the DOM to be loaded, see [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). Does the browser console show any JS errors?

Comment: Do you mean if the console shows me any errors if I put the JS code inside a .js file?

Comment: Yes exactly, are there any errors shown? Can you confirm via the network loading tab that the file is actually loaded? And that the code is executed?

Comment: I checked, so in the console are not any errors, I tried to acces the link from the src of the ```<script>``` tag and the js code is loaded on the page but I think the problem is from the ajax. Can you please give me a code exemple in this case of how can I use ```$(document).ready(function(){});```

Comment: Just wrap your code with it, i.e. in your external JS file do `$(document).ready( function() { ... here goes your existing code ... });`. Make sure to add a `console.log('')` or two in your code to see if it's actually being loaded.

Comment: I did, the code is loaded, even the $.ajax() is loaded, I tested with console.log. It's possible the getElementById to not work properly?

Comment: So you see the requests from `$.ajax()` to your server being made in the network tab? And there are still no errors in the console? Yes `getElementById` could not find the element but I can't answer that question without seeing the template. You probably want to further debug by adding more `console.log` statements and seeing step by step if the `$.ajax()` response is correct, if the elements are found, and so on.